# Problem in reading the contents of the manifest file

Tags: android

hello i downloaded the apk file for the android application called othikyatha (http://code.google.com/p/othikyatha/) from Google Code. i have tried running the project along with the source code obtained from http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Location/othikyatha/Catalogothikyatha.htm. And i have not been able to view the contents of the xml files in /res folder and manifest file. the contents appear encrypted. is there a way of decrypting the contents of these xml files??

Answer (score 0):

The `/res` folder content is not encrypted. It was compiled into binary format for faster parsing in runtime. If you want to de-compile these files, you can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).

But I can save you some time, as you probably tried to use data from .apk file, instead of downloading the source code. The `AndroidManifest.xml` is available via [this link](http://code.google.com/p/othikyatha/source/browse/trunk/Othikyatha/AndroidManifest.xml). You can view all other resource file from that link as well.

Comment: thanks you so much mr.inazaruk .... one more doubt .... how do i run an android project which has multiple java files in the same package ??

Comment: could you please help me out?